# REST API using Zend Framework - is it possible to generate pdf document

Tags: zend-framework, rest, pdf-generation

I'm developing a REST API using Zend Framework. I would have to be able to generate reports as .pdf documents.

How would it be handled? Would the URI be something like `http://api.example.com/reports` ?

Since I'm actually generating it every time based on the input values, would that be against REST principles (i.e. not being cacheable) ? Could the input values be sent as binary (in order to do something like HTML to PDF) ?

Also, if there were multiple types of reports, how would the client be able to select which report to generate ? Would I be having ids similar as if it were a usual resource (so that I would have `http://api.example.com/reports/<reportId>`) ?

What would the business logic be? Should I save the file on the server and return a download link? Would I return the .pdf document as binary without saving it on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the request-header 'Accept' to 'application/pdf'. You could also specify in your URL that you are requesting a PDF-document by using URL-parameters: `http://api.example.com/reports?type=pdf`

`http://api.example.com/reports/<reportId>` is a good way to present individual reports to the user.

How you implement it depends on your needs. Will you need to generate the same reports a lot? If you don't need them much, I don't see the need for you the keep them on the server.

Comment: I'll be having a collection of different reports from which the user can choose which one to generate.
The generated reports are going to change almost every time based on the data from the DB, so I believe it would be pointless to keep them on the server.
In this case, I believe it should be a GET call to `http://api.example.com/reports/<reportId>`, but how would the response contain the pdf file (ie, should I return it as binary, or some other way)? Which http code should be returned?

Also, is it possible to send HTML data to the server and return a pdf document out of that data?